# Invoice is missing the "TotalAmt" field

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We are using the Intuit API V2 to import Invoices from QuickBooks Online.

We expect the "TotalAmt" field to be present on all the invoices.
There are a couple of invoices that at one point in the past had the "TotalAmt" present but now the "TotalAmt" field is missing and the "Balance" is equal to 0.

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

**Edit**: this is one of the responses we got from the QuickBooks API (I changed only the indentation and replaced real data with 3 dots):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>    
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.    com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1">
  <Id idDomain="QBO">36673</Id>
  <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2013-04-10T15:24:03-07:00</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-11T08:32:11-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <Header>
    <DocNumber>...</DocNumber>
    <TxnDate>2013-04-10-07:00</TxnDate>
    <Note>...</Note>
    <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">464</CustomerId>
    <ToBePrinted>true</ToBePrinted>
    <ToBeEmailed>false</ToBeEmailed>
    <SalesTermId idDomain="QBO">1</SalesTermId>
    <DueDate>2013-04-10-07:00</DueDate>
    <BillAddr>
      <Line1>...</Line1>
      <City>...</City>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>...</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>...</PostalCode>
      <Tag>CUSTOMER</Tag>
    </BillAddr>
    <ShipAddr>
      <Line1>...</Line1>
      <City>...</City>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>...</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>...</PostalCode>
      <Tag>CUSTOMER</Tag>
    </ShipAddr>
    <ShipMethodId idDomain="QBO"/>
    <Balance>0.00</Balance>
    <DiscountTaxable>true</DiscountTaxable>
  </Header>
  <Line>
    <Desc>...</Desc>
    <Taxable>false</Taxable>
    <ItemId idDomain="QBO">5</ItemId>
    <UnitPrice>450</UnitPrice>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
  </Line>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: Can you please share the response XML.
You should get both the fields in the response.
Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/invoice

You can test this using apiexplorer tool
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Balance>0.00</Balance>
```

It indicates the amount associated with that invoice is 0. In this case, response XML doesn't include any "TotalAmt" field.

There can be couple of cases where 'TotalAmt' doesn't get included.

### 1.

I had created an invoice with amount as 0. PFB that invoice record in QBO and the corresponding response XML.

[image]

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
  <Id idDomain="QBO">50</Id>
  <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
  <MetaData>
    <CreateTime>2013-07-01T01:59:37-07:00</CreateTime>
    <LastUpdatedTime>2013-07-01T01:59:37-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
  </MetaData>
  <Header>
    <DocNumber>1016</DocNumber>
    <TxnDate>2013-07-01-07:00</TxnDate>
    <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">6</CustomerId>
    <ToBePrinted>false</ToBePrinted>
    <ToBeEmailed>true</ToBeEmailed>
    <SalesTermId idDomain="QBO">3</SalesTermId>
    <DueDate>2013-07-31-07:00</DueDate>
    <BillAddr>
      <Line1>Park Avenue NY</Line1>
      ...
    </BillAddr>
    <ShipAddr>
      <Line1>Park Avenue NY</Line1>
      ... 
    </ShipAddr>
    <BillEmail>john_doe@digitalinsight.mint.com</BillEmail>
    <ShipMethodId idDomain="QBO" />
    <Balance>0.00</Balance>
    <DiscountTaxable>true</DiscountTaxable>
  </Header>
  <Line>
    <Desc>Beer HB</Desc>
    <Taxable>true</Taxable>
    <ItemId idDomain="QBO">4</ItemId>
  </Line>
</Invoice>
```

### 2.

If you don't pass any value in the 'Amount' field of  tag
or
If you skip that field altogether.

PFB sample request and response.

Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
    <Header>
        <Msg>Testing</Msg>
        <CustomerId>6</CustomerId>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Desc>Pens</Desc>
        <Amount></Amount>
        <Taxable>true</Taxable>
        <ItemId>3</ItemId>
        <UnitPrice>450</UnitPrice>
        <Qty>1</Qty>
    </Line>
</Invoice>
```

Response

```
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:qbp="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:qbo="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
    <Id idDomain="QBO">57</Id>
    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2013-07-01T02:48:48-07:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-07-01T02:48:48-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Header>
        <DocNumber>1022</DocNumber>
        <TxnDate>2013-07-01-07:00</TxnDate>
        <Msg>Testing</Msg>
        <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">6</CustomerId>
        <ToBePrinted>false</ToBePrinted>
        <ToBeEmailed>false</ToBeEmailed>
        <DueDate>2013-07-01-07:00</DueDate>
        <BillAddr>
            <Line1>Park Avenue NY</Line1>
            ...
        </BillAddr>
        <ShipAddr>
            <Line1>Park Avenue NY</Line1>
            ...
        </ShipAddr>
        <ShipMethodId idDomain="QBO" />
        <Balance>0.00</Balance>
        <DiscountTaxable>true</DiscountTaxable>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Desc>Pens</Desc>
        <Taxable>true</Taxable>
        <ItemId idDomain="QBO">3</ItemId>
        <UnitPrice>450</UnitPrice>
        <Qty>1</Qty>
    </Line>
</Invoice>
```

I guess, the second one is applicable in your case.

Please let me know if it answers your qts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Amount in the Line is not being set. The Amount is a required field that needs to be set. Here is the doc: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/invoice

The total amount  field will be calculated

thanks
Jarred

Comment: But we do not send any data to QuickBooks, we only retrieve it. The XML response I added to the answer is what we get back from QuickBooks. Since the amount field is required, why is it missing from the response?

Comment: Could you open a support ticket and send me the realmid and the entire response you are getting. I'll take a closer look.